# Merge PDF document but with conditions

Tags: scripting, pdf, merge

I make bus timetable booklets for drivers every day, and I have 4 PDF files:

- Special Instruction Sheet (Every day different)
- Bus daily timetable (which is always different)
- Bus Assistant daily report (internal form, always the same)
- Bus Driver Daily Report (internal form, always the same)

So I can print them double-sided and stapled from a photocopier, I have been using PDFEscape.com to manually put them into the following order:

A=front side of A4 paper. 
B=reverse side of A4 paper.

1a. Special Instructions

1b. BLANK PAGE

2a. Timetable

2b. BLANK PAGE

3a. Timetable

3b. BLANK PAGE

.......

R-2a. Timetable second-last page

R-2b. BUS ASSISTANT FORM

R-1a. Timetable last page

R-1b. BUD DRIVER FORM

The timetables are individual PDFs exported from a scheduling program, and the problem is they are not always the same number of pages (usually 1-5, but can be up to 15).

It is so time-consuming. Does anyone know what script I could write that will do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. What are `a` and `b`? The two sides of a sheet? Could you give us an example? What is `R` and why is it different from the numbered pages? Have you considered doing this in LaTeX?

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable with Python, then pyPDF2 may be an option. For example, it is used by the PDF Shuffler GUI program. Its functionality fits your requirements well, and in the "sample code" directory of the project there's one file which shows how to merge separate PDFs into one. Caveat: I've never worked with it myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the `poppler-utils` package and use `pdfseparate` to split a pdf into separate pages, one pdf per page, and then `pdfunite` to join them in your wanted order back into one pdf.